# Image not being displayed in UIImageView pulled from website

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, image

I have an app which is pulling the image and displaying it in a UIImageView. I have code that I know is working for pulling the images so I think it has to do something with the HTML. I triple check all of the connections in xcode and all are connected. If you could tell me why the image is not being pulled, that would be great! I am pulling from [this](http://www.weather.com/weather/today/CAXX0518:1:CA) website if you want to go look at all of the HTML yourself, but I want the "Right now" image.

[image]

Code to pull image:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.urlForFeelsLike = @"http://www.weather.com/weather/today/CAXX0518:1:CA";
    NSURL *myURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString: [self.urlForFeelsLike stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL2];
    [webViewForFeelLike loadRequest:request2];
    webViewForFeelLike.delegate = self;

    timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(loadImageForCurrentCondition) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)loadImageForCurrentCondition {

    js = @"document.getElementsByClassName('wx-weather-icon')[0].src;";
    imgLink = [webViewForFeelLike stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
    imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imgLink];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImageViewImage) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)setImageViewImage {

    imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgURL];
    image   = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        if (image == nil) {


        }
        else {

            [currentConditionImageView setImage:image];

        }

    });

    NSLog(@"Weather image reloaded");
}
```

HTML line I am pulling from:

```
<div class="wx-data-part wx-first"><img src="http://s.imwx.com/v.20131006.214956/img/wxicon/120/26.png" height="120" width="120" alt="Cloudy" class="wx-weather-icon">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript is wrong.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('wx-weather-icon') //Always returns an array, so you want:
document.getElementsByClassName('wx-weather-icon')[0].src;
```

On another note:

dcorbatta is right below as well, you're using UIWebView incorrectly here. Also, if you're using a UIWebView just to get that image, you're doing things in a very slow, unnecessarily intensive way. UIWebView spends a lot of memory rendering and parsing (it's intended for browsing), when something simpler would accomplish the same feat faster and more efficiently. I'd recommend loading the page as an HTML string, and parsing that string instead.

Comment: Still nothing in the image view

Comment: What do you think the best solution would to do? How would I accomplish that?

Comment: `[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:];`. I feel like pulling out an XML/HTTP parser here would be overkill, so I'd say split the string, or use Regex. I've just committed two sins in one stroke here, so. It's really up to you however.

Comment: Yes, splitting the string is probably the simplest way to go about this.  I plugged in some of your code and everything was working when the correct URL was used.

Side note: You are passing arguments to the selector `setImageViewImage`, but not using them.  Either don't pass anything and use instance variables (as you are doing), or better yet, practice encapsulation and only pass the data you need to the selector.

Comment: Ok but why is the image not loading? I know it is the right link but nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use an NSTimer? You can use the WebView delegate method: `webViewDidFinishLoad:`
And why do you extract the image url from the html? The image src going to change in a near future?

Answer (score 0):

```
 As i have seen the link you gave. i Checked the css&HTML of the link the are not using the       "Rightnow" image. with our web view we can create backgrounds. and you css code is good it is   loading cloud image exactly.

i used the link [link]http://s.imwx.com/v.20131006.214956/img/wxicon/120/26.png where this is     a cloud image.. go to w3schools site and type/paste
```

[link]http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_default

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make any sense, could you explain?

Comment: i used the link [link]http://s.imwx.com/v.20131006.214956/img/wxicon/120/26.png where this is a cloud image..

Comment: Yes but that image will change depending on the weather. It won't always be that image.

Comment: I guess either they will be changing the image url or add some scripts to the image. So, get 2 image urls and change accordingly based on climate status